# Detect changes within QStandardItemModel

Tags: model, qt5, qstandarditemmodel

In order to save a QStandardItemModel to file, I would like to detect if changes where made to the model or not.

Changes may be:

- Update of items
- Deletion of items
- New items (add / insert)
- Movement of items (e.g. wihtin a tree)

The idea is to set a bool to true if a change is detetced.

**How can the model be monitored with respect to changed data?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model emits all sorts of signals when any change happens. Just look into its base class (`QAbstractItemModel`). Connect to those signals and you'll be able to know exactly which changes are happening.

Comment: Right, I was 1) hoping to find a single method and 2) have problems because the appendRow seems not to throw a corresponding signal...

Comment: It'll emit `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted`?

Comment: I connected to the second one (without success) but I'll double check tomorrow.